# Удаление первого элемента двусвязного списка

Tags: c++, список

Реализую двусвязный список на С++ без использования STL.

```
struct DLNode {    //узел списка
    int d;
    DLNode * next,
           * prev;
};

DLNode * AddHeadDL (int data, DLNode * head) {
    DLNode * temp = new DLNode;
    temp->d = data;
    temp->next = head;
    if (head)
        head->prev = temp;
    head = temp;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    return head;
} //функция, добавляющая элемент в начало списка и возвращающая указатель на начало списка

DLNode * RemoveHeadDL (DLNode * head) {
    if (head) {
        DLNode * cur = head;
        head = head->next;
        cur->next = NULL;
        delete cur;
        cur=NULL;
    }
    if (!head)
        cout << "head is null" << endl;
return head;
} //функция, удаляющая первый элемент из списка и возвращающая указатель на список

void ListAll (DLNode * head) {
    if (head) {
        DLNode * cur = head;
        while (cur) {
            cout << cur->d << endl;
            cur=cur->next;
        }
    }
} //функция вывода списка в консоль

/*Текст основной программы*/
int main()
{
    DLNode * head = 0;
    head = AddHeadDL (21, head);
    ListAll (head);
    if (!head->next)
        cout << "end is null" << endl;
    if (!head->prev)
        cout << "prev is null" << endl;
    if (head)
        cout << "list isn't empty" << endl;
    RemoveHeadDL (head);
    if (!head)
        cout << "success" << endl;
    else
        cout << head->d << endl;
    _getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

После удаления единственного элемента из списка, он продолжает оставаться непустым. При этом, если сделать простую проверку и внутри функции `RemoveHeadDL` после строки `head = head->next;` осуществить вывод в консоль: `if (!head) cout << "head is null" << endl;`, можно легко убедиться, что `head` никуда не указывает, как и должно быть. Однако, сразу же после использования функции `RemoveHeadDL` в `main`, выясняется что `head` все же указывает на некий узел, содержащий некоторое значение.
В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны вызывать функцию удаления элемента следующим образом

```
head = RemoveHeadDL (head);
```

Иначе `head` в `main` не изменится.

Помимо этого в самой функции значение `head->prev` не устанавливается в `NULL`.

Функция может быть написана следующим образом

```
DLNode * RemoveHeadDL( DLNode * head ) 
{
    if ( head ) 
    {
        DLNode * cur = head;
        head = head->next;
        if ( head ) head->prev = NULL;
        delete cur;
    }

    if (!head)
        cout << "head is null" << endl;

    return head;
} //функция, удаляющая первый элемент из списка и возвращающая указатель на список
```

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что правильный (или более общий) подход к построению двусвязного списка, это представление его в виде пары указателей, один на голову (на первый), а второй на хвост (на последний) элементы списка.

Comment: @Vlad Благодарю за очень быстрый отклик, решение проблемы и дельное замечание!